# How to edit and update PHP script like Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to ask if there is a software that could help me in mantaining and managing my Wordpress+Plugin modified version.

The problem is that I have a certain number of hacks made to the core and to some plugins I am using, and at every update of a plugin or the core I have to remember to save my hacks and merge with the new source.

I am using **Notepad++** and **WinMerge** for these tasks.

Do you know a software or do you have any suggestions that could help me in improve my manual workflow process.

Thank you in advance, for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start using version control such as Subversion / Git (i.e. TortoiseSVN client) for windows.

You can then maintain your code as a "branch" and keep the wordpress updates in the trunk, when you want to release you "merge" the branch into the trunk and then "tag" the release.

There will be a learning curve involved in this, however I do recommend version control going forward, as it's easy to forget those changes you made xMonths ago, but not with version control when you can historically jump back in time to that revision you made and see exactly what you did.

Comment: @Oneiroi
thank you, and do you know if exists and IDE that supports PHP and Subversion/Git?

Comment: @marco.ragogna Eclipse will I suggest using the Yoxos service here: http://eclipsesource.com/en/downloads/eclipse-galileo-download/ to customize your eclipse for download.

You can see a very quick screen cast on how to do this I have created here:  http://screencast.com/t/Njc0YzMyYWQ

Comment: Thank you for the info, probably is not easy as I tought, but I will try.